# Angular material select not binding correctly the object value

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-forms

I have a very simple angular material select component that's filled from an array of objects. I tried the double way binding with ngModel and the component select attribute but both don't work as expected.

**What I am expecting:** 
Changing the selected option updates the ngModel value with accordingly.

**What actually happens:**
Changing the selected option fires the select change method but don't update the binded attribute.

**How to reproduce:**
Select the Option2 and then go back to Option1, play only with 2 options.

**Where to reproduce:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qpk2di

Comment: the stackblitz works for me. I see the selected value being updated, and the binding `selectedOption.value` as well. Switching between 1 -> 2 -> 1 -> 2

Comment: What browser are you using, because I tested on Firefox and Chrome latest versions and both are not working correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So your error is actually not that complicated you have wrongly used the [()] braces

1. [] is to bind a value to a variable
2. () is for event handling

you used a eventhandler and "databinder" on value `[(value)]`, but you only want to bind

`[value] = "selected option"`

the event is handled with the `(selectionOnChange)="handleYourEvent()"` event

Comment: You are my superhero :D Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can transform your object into a string with JSON.stringify to bind it and after reparse it into an object with JSON.parse to use it in your TS file.

```
In your ts file : 

stringifyValue(value) {
    return JSON.stringify(value); 
}

parseValue(value) {
    let selectedObj = JSON.parse(value); 
}

in your html :

<mat-select (selectionChange)="parseValue($event.value)" >
   <mat-option *ngFor="let obj of options" 
   [value]="stringify(obj)">{{ obj.name }}
   </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```